# Handling the 401 Unauthorized error from rails api when using a partial frontend (react)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.7. My front-end is react and the I'm trying to access my projects route. Login/logout is handled by the rails app/semi-api (it has views for other stuff except for the projects page, which is ). **I do understand that I need a token to pass the authentication check but I can't seem to find any help on how to acquire it from rails. Any documentation/blog/post would be great.**
My rails app uses Devise for authentication and Pundit for authorization.

Sending a GET request from the react app (using axios) immediately redirects the rails application to render the the signin page (as it should in the case of an unauthorized login).
[Snippet of the error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToHu8.png)

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/projects'

function getAPIData(){
  return axios.get(API_URL).then((response) => response.data)
  
}

function App() {
  const [bugs, setBugs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getAPIData().then((items) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setBugs(items);
      }
    });
    return () => (mounted= false);
  }, [])

  return (<Router>
    <Header title='Backend'/>
    <BugList bugs={bugs}/>
    <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Above posted is my axios routine for getting data. React runs on port 4000 and my rails app (using rack-cors with a wildcard(*) expression to accept all requests of all types) on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/projects'

function getAPIData(){
  return axios.get(API_URL)
  .then((response) =>
      response.data).catch((err) => {
        if (err?.response?.status === 401) {
          
        }
  })
  
}

function App() {
  const [bugs, setBugs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getAPIData().then((items) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setBugs(items);
      }
    });
    return () => (mounted= false);
  }, [])

  return (<Router>
    <Header title='Backend'/>
    <BugList bugs={bugs}/>
    <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's not that I want to catch the error, thanks for pointing that out. As I have stated in my question, I would like to bypass authentication by using the authentication token. How do I get that, given my current setup.